# Why does a select statement throw an error when channel is blocked

Tags: go

In this example, the channel is full so the first case in the select statement will block, causing the default case to print. Or at least that's what I thought should happen. Instead I get the error "all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!". Why is this? I thought the select statement blocks until one of the cases can run, which is the default case in this example.

```
 func main() {
        c := make(chan int)
        c <- 1
    
        select {
            case c <- 5:
                fmt.Println("a")
            default:
                fmt.Println("only case not blocked")
            // fatal error: all goroutines are asleep - deadlock!
    }
    }
```

Comment: The panic message shows where the program is blocked:  `c <- 1`.  Send on an unbuffered channel does not proceed until a receiver is ready.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Execution is not even getting to the select statement, as it is deadlocking before that. You're trying to send to the channel you just created, but it's unbuffered - there's nothing to read from it. So the program deadlocks, correctly telling you that all goroutines are blocked. Remove the send before the select and you'll see the expected behavior.

Answer (score 2):

Channels are made for goroutines communication.
When a channel is full, the sender waits for another goroutine to receive it.

The unbuffered channel is an always full one: there must be another goroutine to take what the sender sends (at the same time).

in this part, you write into a channel:

```
c <- 1
```

this one also writes into unbuffered channel, which blocks it:

```
case c <- 5:
```

this example based on your code to show how it works:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    c := make(chan int)
    go func() {
        fmt.Println(<-c) // starting goroutine and continuously reading from chan "c"
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond) //to let goroutine start before program ends

    select {
    case c <- 5: // write into the channel so goroutine can read
        fmt.Println("a")
    default:
        fmt.Println("only case not blocked")
    }
    time.Sleep(time.Millisecond) //to let goroutine start before program finishes
}
```